# subsetting data frame by groups

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df
grp  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6
1   u.3 187 189 141 143 
1   u.3 190 192 144 146             
3   u.3 211 213 165 167             
4   u.3 223 225 177 179         
4   u.3 226 228 180 182
```

I would like to group these data based on the grp column. If grp is repeated (it can repeat several times) for example in the first two rows, then the output should look like this:

```
grp      V2   V3   V4
  1     u.3  187  192
```

Notice how the output has the value from x$V3[1] from the first grp 1 occurrence and the last occurrences V4 value (x$V4[2] is 192).

The output for df should look like this:

```
df.out
grp  V2  V3  V4
1   u.3 187 192                 
3   u.3 211 213             
4   u.3 223 228
```

Comment: Ask your question clearly. why do want to have those values?? what is the criteria? after grouping what are you looking for? minimum value?maximum value? what is it?

Comment: I would like to group by grp and get the min and max value starting from column V3 (min) and ending in V4 (max)

Comment: Can there be more than 1 unique entries in `V2` for each group of `grp`?

Answer (score 2):

This is `dplyr` solution to the problem. Install the package dplyr if don't have it installed.

```
library(dplyr)
dat.out <- dat.in %>% group_by(grp) %>%
              summarize(V2 = unique(V2),V3 = min(V3),V4 = max(V4))
```

Comment: Edited the answer now it will work. Added unique to the V2. Accept my answer if it works for you.

Comment: Im actually getting this error: _Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE_

Comment: @user3141121.  Are you getting the error on the example dataset you showed?  I tried it and the code works perfectly for the example provided.

Comment: The error *length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE* is usually caused by having loaded plyr AFTER dplyr. Use dplyr::summarise to avoid the error, and fix the order in which you load the libraries!

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on a function and an apply loop - and should also do the job.
EDIT: Misunderstood the criteria you extracted values on, disregard if not the first and the last value of V3 and V4.

```
ValExt <- function(g) {
   #Extract first V3 value of the group
   fstV3 <- head(df[which(df$grp==g),"V3"],1)

   #Extract last V4 value of the group
   lstV4 <- tail(df[which(df$grp==g),"V4"],1)

   #Return a row with the group and values
   return(c(g,
            head(df[which(df$grp==g),"V2"],1),
            fstV3,
            lstV4)
            )
}

df.out <- sapply(unique(df$grp),ValExt)
```

Comment: @akrun Yes maybe, but as the function extracts only one grp at a time, the order of the grp variable is not important. If the order of V3 and V4 matters, then you're absolutely right.

Comment: @akrun No, I just pressed enter to fast. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[ ,list(V2=unique(V2), V3=min(V3), V4=max(V4)), by=grp]
#    grp  V2  V3  V4
# 1:   1 u.3 187 192
# 2:   3 u.3 211 213
# 3:   4 u.3 223 228
```